# Java generic issue because of Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, generics, spring-ioc

I've installed eclipse:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
Build id: 20171218-0600
```

java version is:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b16, mixed mode)
```

I imported project here. Project correctly builds with maven and correctly run. But my  eclipse gives me error because of **`COMPILATION ERROR`**. I know what is `COMPILATION ERROR` but it is not, I know that is eclipse issue to handle generics.

To be sure that nothing broken I used `mvn` via terminal - it works correctly also but not in eclipse.

*Corrupted Code example*

```
@Component
public class PagingServiceBuilder<T extends DateTimeApi> {
    @Autowired
    private PagingServiceBuildHelper<?> pagingServiceBuildHelper;

    @NotNull
    private List<DateTimeApi> cutEventsPortion(Pageable pageable, List<DateTimeApi> events,
                                               PageableDirection direction) {
        if (pageable.getPageSize() > Constants.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE) {
            List<DateTimeApi> sortedEvents = pagingServiceBuildHelper.sortByStartDate(events, direction);
            return getEventToBeReturnedInPageObject(sortedEvents, pageable);
        }
        return events;
    }
...
}

@Component
public class PagingServiceBuildHelper<T extends DateTimeApi> {

    List<T> sortByStartDate(List<T> eventDtoList) {
        return sortByStartDate(eventDtoList, PageableDirection.FORWARD);
    }
...
}
```

Eclipse errors me on `sortByStartDate` method call.

I know the issue in general is not with eclipse, it seems my fail with configuring of it (I think this issue can appears with any free IDE). I hope to get advice how to fix the issue. I can work with terminal, but I prefer to use IDE to build and test project in development time.

### P.S

Let me know if I missed some helpful details.

### Add more details

I can run project using eclipse `Java Application` configuration without any issues, but not with eclipse maven plugin. Anyway maven handles correctly it via terminal.

Comment: what kind of Compilation error? with this little information, I don't think we'll be able to help out all that much. is your command prompt (by environment variables) using the same jdk version as your ide? is it using the same instance of maven? ... ?

Comment: It doesn't matter isn't it (in case if project is compilable with jenkins, maven, or on other workstations)? So this is not importan, but any way to answer on your comment: `[ERROR] /Users/~/Documents/projects/calendarservice/src/main/java/com/controller/paging/PagingServiceBuilder.java:[27,67] incompatible types: java.util.List<com.model.api.DateTimeApi> cannot be converted to java.util.List<capture#1 of ?>`

Comment: you would actually believe that not to be important???  DateTimeApi for instance is quite recent, if your environment variables are set to java 8, and your ide or maven used by the ide to java 6, yes, that will give you different results.

Comment: if it is a maven project, try to run Maven -> Update Project. It fixed me a lot of weird eclipse errors. Edit: I see your second comment now, I think my suggestion will not help here, sorry.

Comment: @polis is it maven `task`?

Comment: @Sergii, click right button on Project and choose Maven -> Update Project.

Comment: @polis please add your answer, I'll correct it. Your answer provided me idea to check some important thing, and it was very helpful for me.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it :)

Comment: Does Eclipse still show the compile error if you change `private PagingServiceBuildHelper<?>` to `private PagingServiceBuildHelper<DateTimeApi>`?

Comment: Sure it will after refactoring! But refactoring of working code is unacceptable way to resolve personal eclipse configuration issue. And small correct for change: `private PagingServiceBuildHelper<?> pagingServiceBuildHelper` -> `private PagingServiceBuildHelper<T> pagingServiceBuildHelper`

Comment: @Sergii IMHO, it is not an Eclipse Java IDE bug (see my answer below). `PagingServiceBuildHelper<T>`, but `List<DateTimeApi> cutEventsPortion(... List<DateTimeApi> events ...)` looks odd. I don't know much about Spring, but I would prefer `PagingServiceBuildHelper<DateTimeApi>` also because of `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like a compilation error. Your `pagingServiceBuildHelper` has a Generics parameter of `?`, so `T` in the context of the `sortByStartDate` method is unknown, regardless of what you pass as a parameter.

You could make that method static, if possible, so `T` would be derived from the parameter passed in (what seems to be what you want to achieve):

```
public static <X> List<X> sortByStartDate(List<X> eventDtoList) {
  return sortByStartDate(eventDtoList, PageableDirection.FORWARD);
}
```

Same, of course, for the called two-param `sortByStartDate` method.

Or, if you do not want to make it static, still the Generics parameter should be method-local:

```
@Component
public class PagingServiceBuildHelper {

    public <T extends DateTimeApi> List<T> sortByStartDate(List<T> eventDtoList) {
        return sortByStartDate(eventDtoList, PageableDirection.FORWARD);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you time and your answer I vote for it. But it seems like workaround. Why do you think `public class PagingServiceBuildHelper<T extends DateTimeApi>` worser than `public static <X> List<X> sortByStartDate(List<X> eventDtoList)` or any other your proposition? Do you really think if java compiler can handle it correctly I should fix project syntax but not IDE configuration?

Comment: Well, fixing the code is not really a "workaround" IMO :-) My static proposition was only to show that your Generics parameter T seems to be independent of your helper class, but only relevant to the method's context. For me, this is more about what you really want to express with your method's signature than what any compiler is willing to accept.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a maven project, try to run Maven -> Update Project. It fixed me a lot of weird Eclipse errors. Click right button on Project and choose Maven -> Update Project.

Comment: The issue partly was with maven. Because default maven provided by eclipse knows nothing about my local maven configuration (special repositories), so I've changed it. But my general question part is not resolved yet. I vote for your answer, but can mark it as issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Your given code example without Spring annotations looks as a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as follows:

```
class Foo<T extends Number> {

    Foo<?> foo;

    void cut(List<Number> events) {
        foo.sort(events);
    }

    void sort(List<T> l) {}

}
```

Both the Oracle compiler (`javac`; at least of JDK 8 and 9) and the Eclipse compiler show the compiler error you mentioned. To fix it, change the line

```
private PagingServiceBuildHelper<?> pagingServiceBuildHelper;
```

to

```
private PagingServiceBuildHelper<DateTimeApi> pagingServiceBuildHelper;
```

If the code has worked so far, this could be because a step is done before compiling (maybe some preprocessing related to Spring or to Maven). As the verifiable example shows, it is not caused by a bug in the Eclipse Java IDE. Maybe it is caused by a bug of the Spring or of the Maven plug-in or of an incorrect Eclipse Spring/Maven preferences/settings.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in pom.xml you set one java version (say 1.8), but in Eclipse in project's settings choosen different version of Java, less than 1.8.